# Adding Material UI Icon to a FontIcon Material-UI component in React

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I'm trying to display a Material-UI Icon with a Material-UI `FontIcon` component in React. My code:

```
<FontIcon className="material-icons"/> 
    Help 
</FontIcon>
```

Only text is displayed on the screen.

The Icon is the Help icon from https://material.io/icons/ . The icon library was installed. According to http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/font-icon we should

> If the icon font supports ligatures, reference the font in the `className` and enclose the icon name in the FontIcon tag. I installed the library, but I'm not sure why it is not working?

What is the right way to implement this?

Comment: Have you imported `FontIcon` from `'material-ui/FontIcon'`?

Comment: @JohnKennedy Yes I have. Is my syntax correct?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

From the example at the link you provided, it says the public font should be referenced in the code.

```
<FontIcon className="material-icons" style={iconStyles}>home</FontIcon>
```

You could decide to download the icons using npm:

```
npm install material-design-icons
```

Or better yet add the code below to the `head` section of your main html file.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
  rel="stylesheet">
```

For your case, it should be:

```
<FontIcon className="material-icons">help</FontIcon>
```

> Note I used the lowercase `help` and not `Help` for icon name.

I want to think that the self closing `<FontIcon className="material-icons" />` was a typo, it should be without `/>` since it has a closing `</FontIcon>` tag.

Comment: Thanks. However, I have already installed the library from NPM ("npm install material-design-icons"). I changed "Help" to "help" which just ended up in printing "help" instead.

Comment: Have you imported it, I'd suggest using the `link` version instead.

Comment: When I added the link tag to the html the icon was rendered. It seems either failed, either was not enough.

Comment: Using the `link` is enough.

Comment: What do u mean by "have you imported it?" should I import the stylesheet like any other css stylesheet in my React component?

Comment: Yeah, you have to import like a stylesheet otherwise it can't use it

Comment: Using the link is enough. But it is usually considered more proffesional and fast to include the library. Isn't it so?